# UPROPERTY destructed after actor construct

Tags: unreal-engine4

I can not understand what the problem is. I created 2 classes AMyActor and UObject. In AMyActor, there is a UObject field marked as a property. For some reason, after the AMyActor constructor, the garbage collector deletes the UObject object.

MyActor.h

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "MyObject.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    UPROPERTY()
    UObject *obj;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UStaticMeshComponent *mesh;
};
```

MyActor.cpp

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#include "MyActor.h"


// Sets default values
AMyActor::AMyActor()
{
    // Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    obj = NewObject<UMyObject>();
    mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>("ms");
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("actor create %d %d"), this, obj);
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AMyActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("actor %d %d"), this, obj);
}
```

MyObject.h

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "UObject/NoExportTypes.h"
#include "MyObject.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class MYPROJECT2_API UMyObject : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UMyObject()
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("object create %d"), this);
    }

    ~UMyObject()
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("object destroy %d"), this);
    }
};
```

Output

```
PIE: New page: PIE session: Minimal_Default (Feb 17, 2019, 7:48:39 PM)
LogPlayLevel: Creating play world package: /Game/StarterContent/Maps/UEDPIE_0_Minimal_Default
LogTemp: Warning: object create 1801824896
LogTemp: Warning: actor create 1441518592 1801824896
LogPlayLevel: PIE: StaticDuplicateObject took: (0.005484s)
LogAIModule: Creating AISystem for world Minimal_Default
LogPlayLevel: PIE: World Init took: (0.001288s)
LogPlayLevel: PIE: Created PIE world by copying editor world from /Game/StarterContent/Maps/Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default to /Game/StarterContent/Maps/UEDPIE_0_Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default (0.007418s)
LogTemp: Warning: object destroy 1801824896
LogInit: XAudio2 using 'Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio(SST))' : 2 channels at 48 kHz using 32 bits per sample (channel mask 0x3)
LogInit: FAudioDevice initialized.
LogUObjectGlobals: Warning: Failed to find object 'Class /Script/MyProject2.MyProject2GameMode'
LogLoad: Game class is 'GameModeBase'
LogWorld: Bringing World /Game/StarterContent/Maps/UEDPIE_0_Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default up for play (max tick rate 60) at 2019.02.17-17.48.39
LogWorld: Bringing up level for play took: 0.002244
LogContentBrowser: Native class hierarchy updated for 'MovieSceneCapture' in 0.0004 seconds. Added 10 classes and 0 folders.
PIE: Play in editor start time for /Game/StarterContent/Maps/UEDPIE_0_Minimal_Default 0.179
LogBlueprintUserMessages: Late PlayInEditor Detection: Level '/Game/StarterContent/Maps/Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default:PersistentLevel' has LevelScriptBlueprint '/Game/StarterContent/Maps/Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default:PersistentLevel.Minimal_Default' with GeneratedClass '/Game/StarterContent/Maps/Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default_C' with ClassGeneratedBy '/
Game/StarterContent/Maps/Minimal_Default.Minimal_Default:PersistentLevel.Minimal_Default'
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
LogTemp: Warning: actor 1441518592 0
```

Comment: Does it work if you move `obj = NewObject<UMyObject>();` in the BeginPlay() method?

Answer (score 2):

That's not really how UE4 classes work; it's a bit of a headfudge.

A **UCLASS** constructor isn't a function called on your object (i.e. an instance of the class) when it is constructed (as you'd expect using "vanilla" C++ objects). The class constructor is instead responsible for constructing the *Class Default Object* (CDO). The CDO is then used as a template when the class is instantiated. Analogically the CDO is a "master disc" instance of the class used to create other objects. Your **UCLASS** constructor is only ever called once: on the CDO.

So, by calling `NewObject`, you've created a new object and assigned a pointer to that object to the `obj` member of the CDO. You then go on to make an instance of the the actor in the world, and your pointer is null. Your object hasn't been garbage collected; it was never assigned in the first place.

What you need to call instead of `NewObject` is `CreateDefaultSubobject`. This tells the CDO that a new object of the template-specified type should be created when your `AMyActor` actor is instantiated. `NewObject` is for dynamically spawned objects called between `PreInitializeComponents` and `EndPlay` in the actor's lifecyle.

**TL;DR**: Change your `NewObject` call to a `CreateDefaultSubobject` if you want to call it in the constructor. Alternatively move the `NewObject` call to the `PostInitializeComponents` function of your actor.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Objects
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Actors/ActorLifecycle

NB. Be wary that the Objects documentation link provided is woefully out of date (v4.11; I noticed it references `ConstructObject` which has since been deprecated and removed). However what it says about CDOs hasn't changed at time of writing (4.21).